# Is there a method for reading input that's considered more "professional" than scanner class?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I was told by a couple of my professors that that Java Scanner class is meant to be a simple learning tool, but that there are more professional ways to read inputs. Is this true? If so, can one give examples?

Comment: seriously? OK... when you try to login in your gmail/hotmail/... account, do you use the command prompt to login and get your data? or do you expect a nice working UI to fill in the information?

Comment: Opinion-based and unclear question. Inputs are often stored in some format (csv, xml, json). And it's more "professional" to read them using standard parser instead of hand-written Scanner. Also a lot of data is contained in databases, so people use them.

Comment: _I was told by a couple of my professors that that Java Scanner class is meant to be a simple learning tool_ Not true. `Scanner` class definitely has other uses. Can you give an example of the kinds of _inputs_ you wish to read?

Comment: Scanner was not designed as a learning tool.  Either *you* misunderstood them, or they are confusing `Scanner` with the `StdIn` / `StdOut` / etc classes that some schools use for teaching.

Comment: Sorry for the vague nature of the question. It's possible that they were referring to the Buffered Reader class as the two below mentioned. At the time we weren't given much context for why they made those comments.

Comment: @SamuelForel I guess you are on your first year learning Java basics. Just wait a little you will start learning Java FX or creating simple UI and you will understand that Scanner is not always used for getting user input

Answer (score 2):

As you mention the Java Scanner class in a context of learning, I assume you are talking about reading the user's input from console.

I don't know if the Scanner class was created with learning purposes but certainly there are better ways of reading input from the console.

The scanner class may suit you in a normal scenario but if for example you need to read a really fast or irregular input synchronized perfectly with some events on the program then it might give you some problems. For example the **BufferedReader** class would be the best solution here.

You can read about the "topic" [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ways-to-read-input-from-console-in-java/).

A Buffer basically allows you to receive information at "any" speed and retrieve it in a constant flux. The easiest example of buffering is Youtube:
You are downloading the content of a video through internet, and the internet speed is not always constant. As this happens, if you reproduce "directly" what you are downloading then the video might reproduce x2 times faster or get stuck and pause for half a second, etc...
The solution to this is a buffer where you store all the data you download from the Youtube server and then process it at a constant speed so your video reproduces as it was intended to.

I hope the explanation was clear and helpful, I am still improving my english!

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String str1 = br.readLine();